# How to show time chooser in datepicker on magento configuration

Tags: magento-1.8, datepicker

I am trying to display time chooser in magento date picker but it didn't how up.

can anyone please guide on this how to set timer in magento system confif.

I have followed [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660842/add-a-date-picker-to-system-xml-on-custom-module) Link but it show only date picker.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27567707/7707208

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make changes in the _getElementHtml() function.

Please replace the _getElementHtml() function with below code:

```
protected function _getElementHtml(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
{
    $date = new Varien_Data_Form_Element_Datetime;
    $format = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateTimeFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT);

    $data = array(
        'name'      => $element->getName(),
        'html_id'   => $element->getId(),
        'image'     => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
    );
    $date->setTime(true); // added this new line of code
    $date->setData($data);
    $date->setValue($element->getValue(), $format);
    $date->setFormat(Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateTimeFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT));
    $date->setClass($element->getFieldConfig()->validate->asArray());
    $date->setForm($element->getForm());

    return $date->getElementHtml();
}
```

I have made changes in 3 places:

**Step 1:**

> $date = new Varien_Data_Form_Element_Date;

to

> $date = new Varien_Data_Form_Element_Datetime;

**Step 2:**

> $format = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT);

to

> $format = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateTimeFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT);

**Step 3:**

> $date->setFormat(Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT));

to

> $date->setFormat(Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateTimeFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT));

and

**Step 4:**

> $date->setTime(true); // added this new line of code

Comment: I think this should be `$date = new Varien_Data_Form_Element_Date;` when i use `$date = new Varien_Data_Form_Element_Datetime;` it gives error like `Fatal error: Class 'Varien_Data_Form_Element_Datetime' not found` because there is no file like Datetime in Element folder.

Comment: I have checked my code in Magento 1.9. It may be possible that the class does not exist in Magento 1.8